# compare xml files with maven or ant

Tags: xml, ant, diff, maven, compare

I have a requirement to compare 2 directories of wsdl and xsd files
using maven or ant and to generate a report (preferably html) of the 
differences.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write your own Plugin.  Start with this on the command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=mygroup -DartifactId=myartifact
```

Choose maven plugin from the list.  A plugin project will be generated.

The plugin code will have an `execute()` method, just implement that.  It will be far faster and cleaner to implement this simple method than to hack around with the Ant plugin.  For instance, using normal process exec semantics, you could run a recursive diff of the two directory trees.  Whatever you would do from the command line.

But if it were that simple, to just run a command line, check out http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html first to see if that will solve your problem.  Note that this plugin is not generally portable across operating systems though.  Writing your own plugin is generally preferred for this reason.

You can add this new plugin project to your source tree, Maven will know to build the plugin first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understand you solution. Ideally I would like to avoid writing my own plugin but will do if its the only option.

Comment: A bit more background to what I am doing:

Given a set of WSDLs I am generating services stubs using axis with XMLBeans.

All service operations are creating their soap responses from xml files
which i am manually creating (for the moment).

These WSDLs get updated regularly with little documentation around the changs.

It would be very useful to have a report generated with the differences between
the WSDLs in order to update the soap responses as necessary. 

One project I came accross and will spend a bit of time trying out is AntTask-XMLDiff.

I'll post again if I can get it working.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Have you looked at the Axis plugins for Maven?  And thanks for marking the question answered.  Much appreciated.